# Greater than key?

Tags: libgdx

I’m using the quick way of checking for key events inside the renderer thread:

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(key));
```

But I can’t seem to find a key inside the `Keys` that maps out the greater than key on my keyboard.

Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction?

I’ve tried probably every key that says `RIGHT` something—as this seems as though something that might be it.

### Moreover

It’s worth to notice that when using *LibGDX*’s `InputProcessor`, the greater than and less than signs don’t register at all as for certain keyboard layouts. In the Swedish QWERTY keyboard layout for example, the key for greater than and less that don’t register at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an [InputProcessor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling#input-processor), implement its `keyTyped` method to get a character from the pressed key, which is layout independent:

```
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    switch (character) {
        case '<': 
            // less than pressed
            break;
        case '>':
            // greater than pressed
            break;
        default:
            // whatever
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Keep in mind that there is no good way to poll a character instead of a key, and it's hard to emulate due to a lack of a keyTypedReleased event. As such, you might have to rethink your loop, since you can't check for char presses in the `isCharPressed` fashion that you have now.